# Launching a JAR file using Apache as a background process

Tags: apache, bash, background-process, executable-jar

I have a data parsing utility in the form of a runnable JAR file. I also have an Apache server (Ubuntu 12.04) to which data files are uploaded. Is there anyway that I could launch said JAR file as a background process when a file is uploaded? (FYI: File access by multiple processes isn't a concern here; I've got file locking in place.)

Related idea: if the above isn't possible, I could always launch the aforementioned JAR file from a bash script. However, I'm still not sure how to do that via Apache. I'm quite a novice at using it effectively.

**Edit:** Just noticed [this potential php solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540332/running-bash-scripts-in-php). Apache folks: is this a good idea, or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use [File Alternation Monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Alteration_Monitor) to achieve this. It can be configured as a background daemon which performs operations if the new file is spotted. If you want to avoid starting while the file is currently uploaded, wait approx. 5 minutes after the file change time and start processing your utility.

I use a similar technique for monitoring uploaded files on a Samba share and it works flawless.